# How to prevent Gunicorn from accepting connections from anything other than Nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn

How can I configure my Gunicorn server to accept requests only from my Nginx proxy, denying any direct requests to the Gunicorn port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.  Just don't bind your Gunicorn server to anything outside localhost.  Only other things on the machine will be able to talk to it.  This is the default, so you shouldn't have to do anything, or you can be explicit about it.

```
gunicorn -b localhost:8000 --workers 2 module:app
```

You could bind a Unix socket instead of a TCP socket.  A Unix socket can be file-like, so you can set normal file permissions so that only the Nginx user can read it.  This can be more performant than TCP sockets anyway, but is not really any more secure.